# Have Android app users create and change objects on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I am looking for a strategy to have global objects that can be accessed across all users on all devices. My idea is to create an object or file and put it on Google Cloud Server, and using Datastore, Blobstore, or Cloud Storage (or maybe something else?), and have the object/file change as different users interact with it and alter variable values.

Now, how in the world can I do this - I am having a lot of trouble understanding the documentation that Google offers. Are there any convenient APIs for this? If so, how can these API's be accessed? Currently, I have followed the Android Studio "Hello Endpoints" setup, and I have a working backend module running on AppEngine.

So far I have learned how to create an API and API methods:

```
    @Api(
        name = "myApi",
        version = "v1",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "backend.myapplication.Mike.example.com",
                ownerName = "backend.myapplication.Mike.example.com",
                packagePath = ""
        )
)
public class MyEndpoint {

    /**
     * A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
    public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name) {
        MyBean response = new MyBean();
        response.setData("Hi, " + name);
        return response;
    }

}
```

So this shows I have successfully created a Cloud Endpoints / backend that goes with an App Engine project.

So, what I was hoping to do with this set up is to create an API method to save data to the cloud server, and then have other users on other devices to be able to retrieve that data.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. please provide more info on your application and what you have tried already.

Comment: All instances of your application will have access to the same datastore/memcache/Cloud Storage buckets.... so it's indeed hard to know what you're trying here. You'd need to provide more info, and asking for a tool like an API is just directly off topic here....

Comment: I have updated the question with a little more explanation. Please give it look and let me know if I should provide more information. Thanks. @jirungaray

Comment: @Patrice question updated. thanks.

Comment: You have another question that asks almost the exact same question, but access to data in a web application is the application's role, and the data store is just a bucket with a bit of intelligence. In this specific case, your architecture would be client app <-> internet <-> server app <->data store, so sharing data between multiple client apps is the responsibility of the server, whatever and wherever that is. Using Google cloud, that could be app engine, or your own server instance running on a compute engine VM.

Comment: @regretoverflow Thank you for the recommendations. I have never worked with servers before, so this is all completely new to me - and very confusing to me. Can you give me a general suggestion on where to begin to create my own server functionality on Google App Engine? I think my problem is that I am trying to rely on Google's APIs that already exist?

Comment: That's kind of a broad question too. What programming languages are you familiar with? If I was starting with a blank slate and had any language at my disposal, I'd use app engine and either go or python as my app server language and I'd make sure I have a pure REST api. Here's a link to the app engine docs:https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine

Comment: I'm most familiar with java, would you say Python is worth learning and using over java for app engine? @regretoverflow

Comment: Java is a perfectly acceptable language to write app engine apps on.

Comment: Cool! You've been very helpful. May have some more questions on the topic in the future that I will be sure to post on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something like "a big shared object" that lots of people can all change collaboratively, you might want to check out [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com), which does this and keeps everyone in sync (and integrates nicely with Android and iOS).